# jquery expression to remove tr inside tbody

Tags: jquery

I have some html which looks like this....

```
<body class="BirtViewer_Body" style="overflow:hidden; direction: ltr" leftmargin="0px" scroll="no" onload="javascript:init( );">
<table id="layout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;height:100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="body_caption_top">
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="body_caption" valign="bottom">
<td colspan="2">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1px" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="3px"> </td>
<td>
<b> </b>
</td>
<td align="right"> </td>
<td width="3px"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to remove tr body_caption_top and also tr body_caption. Can someone please help me with the query expression to do this.

Thanks. I am still learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uses jquery remove:

```
$("#layout").find("tr.body_caption, tr.body_caption_top").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('tr.body_caption_top, tr.body_caption').remove();
```

Or you can simply hide them using `.hide()` in the same way.